# SQL - How to check if XML field is damaged/ valid before selecting

Tags: sql, xml, blob, sql-server-2016, corruption

I have a scenario where a table, containing an XML column, will occasionally contain XML data which displays the following error when trying to select it:

"Msg 6611, Level 16, State 1, Line 889
The XML data type is damaged."

I have pin pointed the record with the issue, but it's not something I want to correct at this time but I instead want my select statement to still select data from the table without the whole thing falling over. If there was a way to use a function to check whether the XML is damaged/ valid, if so select a blank value, then this would be my preferred option or if not perhaps just exclude the troublesome record from the results.

Hopefully this made sense and thank you in advance!

Example query which errors (If I exclude the XML column, the query works):

```
SELECT
    T.ID,
    T.XML
FROM
    TableName T
```

Ultimatley, this is the kind of query I'm trying to run (I'd like the value field to display as blank if the XML is damaged):

```
SELECT
    T.ID,
    t.c.value ('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Value
FROM
    TableName T
    CROSS APPLY DocumentXML.nodes('//XMLNode') t(c)
```

Comment: This seems to be SQL-Server... Please tag your question with the RDBMS (including version!) you are using. Is the column `DocumentXML` a native XML typed one?

Comment: This might be [related to this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2803994/fix-data-corruption-occurs-when-lob-data-is-loaded-into-a-transact-sql)

Comment: Sorry, you're using terms I don't understand! Yes it's SQL-Server (hence why I tagged the issue with "sql". SSMS version being run is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU6) (KB4037354) - 13.0.4457.0 (X64).

When you say "native XML typed one" I'm guessing you're asking if the column is the standard XML data type used in SQL, to which the answer is yes.

Comment: According to the link I've stated it can happen, that the underlying object gets currupted.  The only way I can think of is to use a `CURSOR` together with `BEGIN TRY/END TRY` and `BEGIN CATCH/END CATCH` in order to check the readability row by row. You might read about repair methods (`DBCC CHECKDB`), but I doubt, this will help...

Comment: Gosh, if this is the only way to get around it then this may bring the server to its knees (potentially have millions of records in these tables). Thanks for the advice, I'll see how my colleagues would like to proceed. Perhaps a repair is the only way

Comment: If there are millions of records and just a few are broken, it will be faster to check the readability in appropriate chunks...

Comment: The requirement is to select all data from multiple tables (say 50 tables or so), containing XML columns, as they are used for exporting of data. This is why I was hoping to a function or something to check if there were any XML errors, so that we could just ignore those and allow the export to still proceed